# In Visual Studio 2019, how can I see a log of all the received API calls

Tags: visual-studio-2019

In Visual Studio 2019 (running locally), how can I see a log of all the API calls received from a react application running on another local server?  If this isn't possible in Visual Studio 2019, is it possible in a later version?